« que » versus « qui »
In Marceline Desbordes-Valmore's poem Jour d'Orient, the following two lines begin and end the poem:

Ce fut un jour pareil à ce beau jour
Que, pour tout perdre, incendiait l’amour.

I would have expected "Qui" and not "Que". What is the grammatical justification (or at least, the poetic justification) for using "Que" here?

I think that que is COD of incendier et qui would not be possible here: l'amour incendie le jour.

I think that que is COD of the verb incendier. The meaning is that l'amour incendie le jour (love makes that day incandescent), and qui to denote a subject would not work here. Qui would imply that the day makes loves incandescent, which maybe could work, but I don't think is the intended meaning. In fact, you can switch the subject and the meaning by using qui or que.
